# PostAsJsonAsync<string> can't deserialize response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

i trying to get string response from my API and there is some error occured:

Here is my API method:

```
public class AuthenticationController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> PostAsync(CreateTokenCommand credentials)
    {
        string test= "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9";

        return Ok(test);
    }
}
```

Here is my calling method:

```
public async Task Login(UserCredentials model)
    {

        try
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.PostJsonAsync<string>("https://localhost:44373/api/authentication", model);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Text of error:

```
'e' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
```

with stacktrace:

> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& readStack, JsonReaderException ex)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.d__6`1.MoveNext() at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at CheckerApp.WebUI.Services.JWTAuthenticationService.d__3.MoveNext() in D:\MyProjects\CheckerApp\CheckerApp.WebUI\Services\JWTAuthenticationService.cs:line 38

Where did i mistake and how can i fix it?

Comment: It expects to receive a JSON string and "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9" is not  valid JSON. Perhaps `return Ok(new { Test = test });`?

Comment: in that case error become: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.String. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1."  since PostJsonAsync<string> awaitin string responce

Comment: Yeah, because it's not a `string` anymore, but rather an object. Generally, you don't deal with `string` as a base for a JSON. It's either an object or an array

Comment: Hmm, so there is no other way in that situation but create dto object for transporting string value?

Comment: Well, you don't need it in the backend (because of anonymous objects) and in the client you could use `PostJsonAsync<JObject>` and then get the "test" property from the object (I don't remember the exact syntax). Otherwise, don't use JSON for this

Comment: If not JSON, then how could i get it? Would you give me some example please?

Comment: Going back to the code in the question for the server, something like: `var response = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44373/api/authentication", new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model))); var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` (there might be some typo there)

Comment: By the way, with PostJsonAsync<JObject> it also gives exception: "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken]. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 47."

Comment: Well, it gave me some response conaining my string value, but it still need to be parsed. But thanks anyway it helps me a lot!

Comment: Ah, no. My mistake. It still give me wrong response. {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|98474eb3-4efbdf5e2311381f.1.53fabf4b_"}

Comment: It's throwing an error - HTTP415. Probably because of the missing header.. try with `new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(model), Encoding.Utf8, "application/json")`

Comment: Yes, it's helped! Thanks a lot!